# How to remove a section of multiple file names?

Tags: windows-10, rename, batch-rename, wildcards

I have many files with a wildcard section I'm having to manually remove and was wondering if there was a way to do it automatically, for example I would want to rename:

`Perfect Dark#43DDCBF0#2#0#B33D887D_ciByRGBA.png`

to

`Perfect Dark#43DDCBF0#2#0_ciByRGBA.png`

---

There's 4 sections to the file names and the extension.

`Perfect Dark | #43DDCBF0#2#0 | #B33D887D | _ciByRGBA | .png`

The first section is always `Perfect Dark`, the second is `#abcdefgh#i#j`, and the third which I want to remove is `#klmnopqr`, then the fourth is _ followed by either ciByRGBA or all (either `_ciByRGBA` or `_all`). And finally the extension is always `.png`.

---

This would be a huge help if its possible since I have over 1000 files left! Thanks!

Comment: Speedrunner, I presume? https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/ + some regex

Comment: Would this be a correct interpretation: Search for last #, from there search forward to an underscore, and remove everything in between including the #?

Comment: You beat me to it @Gantendo :) ..

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Yeah it is a speedrunning thread after all... We got Karl Jobst in the house!

Comment: @Gantendo ..  Karl Jobst??  WOOT WOOT!  The zelda ocarina run was legendary :)

Comment: @Gantendo I'm actually helping to finish up an old texture pack, and whatever wildcard support that was in glide64 napalm is missing in the modern plugin (I'd imagine it triggered the same issues as adding _all to a texture name). Besides the textures I'm redoing, all that's left are character models (which may have to be done by editing the rom) and multiplayer maps, as well as a few common textures like doors and the back of monitors which don't want to dump. I think I'll be able to get at those by extracting memory cache though.

Comment: `Would this be a correct interpretation: Search for last #, from there search forward to an underscore, and remove everything in between including the #?`

Yeah that should work in all situations, didn't realist a tool like this existed, when I was looking for answers before I only found solutions limited to what the rename command in linux could do over at unix.stackexchange.

Currently using `(.+)#` and `\1` to delete everything after the last #, can't figure out how to stop at the _ though. To bad theres no way to sort by length of file names so I could just add the suffixs easily.

Comment: Ok made a slight mistake as what I asked would removed the #j from names that already have no wildcard. So I just used what I posted above and went through them manually, which only took about 10 minutes. Assuming all names have wildcards and there is still something variable and the _ that you couldn't just add with a suffix, this will work: `(.+)#.*?(_.*)` `\1\2`